# How to expose global strings and ints to C++, QML, and JS

Tags: qt, qml, qtquick2

Our team is developing a Qt application which makes use of C++, QML, and JS. What is the best way to expose non-language specific strings, representing filenames and `int`s representing error codes, so that all languages can easily use them?

Comment: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-cppintegration-topic.html

Answer (score 1):

The most efficient and clean solution would be to implement those strings and ints as properties of a `QObject`, then create an instance of that object in `main.cpp` and register it as a singleton.

```
// before main()
YourType data;
static QObject * getData(QQmlEngine * e, QJSEngine *) {
  e->setObjectOwnership(&data, QQmlEngine::CppOwnership); // just in case
  return &data;
}


// in main()
qmlRegisterSingletonType<YourType>("Core", 1, 0, "Data", getData);
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
//...
```

And now you have a global `data` for C++, and a global `Data` for QML. In the first case you will need to declare `data` as an `extern` in sources which need to access it, in the second case you will need to `import Core 1.0` in order to access `Data` and its properties.

Comment: A singleton creation function should create a new object on each call.
The object is a per-engine singleton and life-time managed by the engine

Comment: @KevinKrammer - the example in the documentation doesn't use the engine parameters whatsoever. It doesn't seem like there is any setting of engine affinity or whatsoever. This seems to work fine, although I personally haven't used it in a multi-engine scenario. This way it can be global in both C++ and QML.

Comment: "NOTE: A QObject singleton type instance returned from a singleton type provider is owned by the QML engine unless the object has explicit QQmlEngine::CppOwnership flag set." http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qqmlengine.html#qmlRegisterSingletonType-1

Comment: From my experience it is best to NOT trust the qml engine with object ownership. It has a history of not deleting stuff it needs to, and what's worse - deleting stuff it really shouldn't.

Comment: In this case you should explicitly set the ownership to C++ owned, like your edit now does